# Нужна ли запятая перед ЛИБО

Tags: запятые

"Сделать возврат и зарегистрировать акт вы можете в шинном центре, в котором приобретали товар, либо обратившись в магазин по адресу..." - нужна ли тут запятая перед ЛИБО, если "в котором приобретали товар" - придаточное предложение?

Comment: Перед ‟либо” нужна запятая, чтобы закрыть определительное придаточное.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая закрывает придаточное предложение. Поэтому она нужна.